# Finding the $\ker$ and $Im$ from an equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> In a $E=\mathbb{R_3}[X]$, we consider that we have $\phi:P\rightarrow(X^2-1)P''+2XP'$. Determine matrice $\phi$ within the canonical basis of $E$. deduce $\ker \phi$ and $Im\phi$.

How to find such a matrice? I don't know how to manage such an equation: $\phi:P\rightarrow(X^2-1)P''+2XP'$

And I don't understand the answer neither:

> In $B=\{1,X,X^2,X^3\}$,
>
> $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
> 0 & 0 & -2 & 0\\
> 0 & 2 & 0 & -6\\
> 0 & 0 & 6 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 12
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> $rang(A)=3$ and $\ker(\phi)=Vect\{1\}$ and $Im(\phi)$ has the following basis $\{\phi(X),\phi(X^2),\phi(X^2)\}$

To my mind the matrix should have the dimension  (3,3) and should be in In $B=\{1,X,X^2\}$ as far as there is no $X^3$ in the $P$ equation. Furthermore it should have been:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

$Rang(A)=3$
$$(x,y,z)\in \ker \phi\begin{cases}
-x=0\\
2y=0\\
z=0
\end{cases}$$

Therefore $\ker\phi=\{0,0,0\}$. $Im \phi$ is easy to find.

Comment: The basis in the answer is a basis for $\Bbb R_3[x]$, which is given as the domain and codomain of $\phi$

Comment: And how did you decide that your matrix is what $A$ should be? Did you have a process here? For example, what is $\phi(x)$, and what does that tell you about the matrix $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${\mathbb R}_3[X]$ is evidently the set of all polynomials of degree $\le3$. The standard ordered basis for this set is $B=(1,x,x^2,x^3)$.

The matrix that represents a linear transformation $\phi$ will map the coordinates of $p$ with respect to $B$ to the coordinate of $\phi(p)$ with respect to $B$.

There is a standard formula for this matrix $A$: The $i$th column of $A$ is the coordinates of $\phi(b_i)$, where $b_i$ is the $i$th element of $B$.

Using the most complicated calculation, as an example, 
$$\eqalign{\phi(x^3) &= (x^2-1)\cdot{d^2\over dx^2}(x^3) + 2x \cdot {d\over dx} (x^3)
\cr&= (x^2-1)\cdot (6x) + 2x \cdot 3x^2 \cr&= 0\cdot 1 +(-6)\cdot x + 0\cdot x^2 + 12\cdot x^3 \cr}
$$
Thus the coordinates of $\phi(x^3)$ (and column $4$ of $A$) is $\left[\matrix{0\cr -6\cr 0\cr 12\cr}\right]$.